# Python: input saving multiline string

Tags: python-3.x, multiline

```
while True:
try:
    line = input("paste:")
except EOFError:
    break

f = open("notam_new.txt", "w+")
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

This code return only the last line of multi-line after Ctrl+D

I tried also:

```
notam = input("paste new notam: ")

f = open("notam_new.txt", "w+")
f.write(notam)
f.close()
```

getting only the first row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `line` in a loop, so every iteration you're just overwriting said line with the next one You need to accumulate your lines in a list (created before the `while True`) so you can keep track of all of them, and then write to the file in a loop. Plus you also need to add a newline as `input()` strips it.

```py
lines = []
while True:
    try:
        lines.append(input("paste:"))
    except EOFError:
        break

with open("notam_new.txt", "w+") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks. 
But how can i remove that:
`paste:paste:paste:paste:paste:` after pasting couple lines?

And is there any other option than Ctrl+D to end it?

Comment: "But how can i remove that: paste:paste:paste:paste:paste: after pasting couple lines? " dunno, don't provide a prompt? Or don't use `input` and read from `sys.stdin` directly (it's more complex but also way more flexible). "And is there any other option than Ctrl+D to end it?" that's up to you, you could break it on C-c instead, or when you get an empty line, or two empty lines in a row.